# What kind of hardware does Microsoft use to build Azure?

Tags: hardware, azure

I'm curious about `Azure` virtual machines and Web/Worker role hardware. What kind of hardware (CPU, Disk, network cards, chipsets, etc..) does Microsoft use to run Azure on? Is there public information available?

Comment: Per the FAQ, "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. " So, I shall make the assumption that you are not building a competitor to MS Azure, and vote to close. This wouldn't be a bad question for Chat, mind you, if anyone knew.

Answer (score 5):

I can answer this, and the answer is....a variety. They buy Intel based kit from at least HP, IBM and Dell and buy their matching disks/memory etc. from those manufactures. Ultimately so long as they keep to their own Hyper-V HCL they can buy what they want but that's what they do, the don't do that Google 'roll-your-own' trick.

Comment: Interesting. Can you source this answer?

Comment: Well this answer is now quite old so may well be out of date but my source is myself having visited two of their datacenters myself.